# Difference between provider.sendTransaction vs signer.sendTransaction?

Tags: javascript, etherjs

I am finding it difficult to see the difference between these two, what are their respective use cases?

Answer (score 3):

Hi Developer advocate from Chainstack here.

Basically `provider.sendTransaction` takes in a hexed string of signed tx as its parameter. `signer.sendTransaction` takes a transaction object as the parameter.

Unless you already have the decoded tx string, you need to use `signer.signTransaction` before sending a transaction using `provider.sendTransaction`.

In fact from ether.js's [source code](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/master/packages/abstract-signer/src.ts/index.ts), this is exactly how it is done at the back.

```
async sendTransaction(transaction: Deferrable<TransactionRequest>): Promise<TransactionResponse> 
{
  this._checkProvider("sendTransaction");
  const tx = await this.populateTransaction(transaction);
  const signedTx = await this.signTransaction(tx);
  return await this.provider.sendTransaction(signedTx);
}
```

Hope this helps, happy coding!

Comment: he needs to use signer.sendTransaction , because I don't think he signs it somewhere else

Comment: Not sure about that but yeah signer.sendTransaction is much more straightforward in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

A signer is a concept from ethersjs ( check their docs). Basically, it's a provider (another ethersjs concept, perhaps a little more transparent, that is just an abstraction of a connection to the ETH network (through an RPC)) + a private key (in practice, it's usually Metamask). Typically, if the signer is metamask, `signer.sendTransaction` will prompt the user with a metamask pop-up asking them to sign and broadcast the transaction.

`Provider.sendTransaction` expects an *already signed* transaction as input, and will simply broadcast it.